# How to set NULL in a Coalesce

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quick question on Coalesce:

```
clw.ClawbackPercent = Coalesce(@ClawbackPercent, clw.ClawbackPercent)
```

Lets say for column 'ClawbackPercent' I have a value of 100.

If I execute a proc and set parameter @ClawbackPercent to have the value NULL, it keeps the value 100 in the row for that column which is great.

However, if I want to set 100 to actually be NULL, what do I need to write in the exec proc statement or what do I need to add in the Coalesce statement?

Thank you

Comment: Then you skip the coalesce expression.

Comment: Can you set out what the set of `@ClawbackPercent` value, current `ClawbackPercent` column value and expected `ClawbackPercent` column value afterwards values for your various scenarios? It sounds at the moment like you expect to be able to set `@ClawbackPercent` to `NULL` in two different scenarios and for us to somehow write a query that magically behaves in two different manners.

Comment: So if the parameter is `NULL`, what should the SP do? Keep the previous value or replace it? I guess you know how to do both.

Comment: Coalesce returns null only if both the parameters are null otherwise it ll return the value which is not null.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want 100 to be the **Default** value of a stored proc parameter, not necessarily to replace all NULLs with this value. If this is the case, you don't want a COALESCE but you do need to provide a default value for the parameter on the proc definition.

e.g.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.MyProc (
@MyParam INT = 100
)
AS
-- My code here
```

If somebody executes this proc without specifying a value for @MyParam, the default of 100 will be assigned. If they explicitly specify @MyParam = NULL then NULL will be assigned..

Answer (score 1):

Then probably you should not use `coalesce`, instead you can use `case` statement as below:

```
clw.ClawbackPercent = CASE WHEN @ClawbackPercent = 100 
                               THEN NULL 
                           ELSE 
                               @ClawbackPercent END
```

in the select statement

Answer (score 0):

You have to write in the following way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test(
    @ClawbackPercent VARCHAR(30)
) AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT COALESCE(@ClawbackPercent, '100')
END
```

--call as below and if you want to return second value then, EXEC sp_test NULL

--if your second, thirds... parameters are in INTEGER then simply CAST to VARCHAR

```
EXEC sp_test 'NULL'
```